# How to upload the shaded jar after maven build?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar

I would like to upload the builded jar with all dependencies via SFTP to my Raspberry Pi. Therefore I tried to use maven-deploy-plugin.

My configuration looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Raspberry Pi</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                <file>target/${project.name}.jar</file>
                <url>sftp://root@192.168.2.108/home/</url>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As you can already see, the uploaded jar is a shaded jar which is renamed by `<finalName>${project.name}</finalName>`

Furthermore I included the wagon-ssh extension and defined the Raspberry Pi:

```
<extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>Raspberry Pi</id>
        <url>sftp://192.168.2.108/home</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

However, if I execute mvn:deploy, maven will only upload the original-jar to the Raspberry Pi to the file path of groupId, artifactId and version.

What can I do to only upload a single jar without a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Deploy plugin Maven will automatically deploy it in a folder named after your artifact groupdId, artifactId, etc. This behavior is built-in and you cannot override it, there's not much you can do about it.

However you can use the [Wagon plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) to directly upload via SSH on your RPI with a configuration like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload-raspberry-pi</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload-single/goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fromFile>target/${project.name}.jar</fromFile>
                <url>sftp://192.168.2.108/home</url>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The upload will bind to the deploy phase, you can then run `mvn deploy` as with the Deploy plugin to have your JAR uploaded on your machine.

Note that if you are using Maven 3 you'll have to update your project dependencies. As per the [Usage](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html) page:

> This plugin does not work with Maven 3.0.x and 3.1.x out of the box
>   due to missing the following libraries in it distribution:
>   commons-io-2.x, common-lang-2.x, and jsoup-1.x. You can invoke
>   wagon:update-maven-3 to add the missing files to $MAVEN_HOME/lib. See
>   WAGON-407 for details